# What is the exponent of 0.00000072

Tags: discrete-mathematics

And how do I solve this?

I know this is a decimal and we have to convert it to an exponent. I want to know how I would solve this and the steps as well so I will be able to solve questions similar to this in the future. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The number 0.00000072 has no exponent.

My best guess is that this question is about [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). Every non-zero real number can be written in the form $\pm d_0.d_1d_2d_3 \ldots \times 10^e$, where $d_0 \neq 0$. Here $e$ is the exponent. Some examples:

- $32 = 3.2 \times 10^1$. The exponent is $1$.
- $-0.0014 = -1.4 \times 10^{-3}$. The exponent is $-3$.
- $3.14159 = 3.14159 \times 10^0$. The exponent is $0$.

Hopefully now you can solve the question on your own.